# Function $f(\textbf{x})=\|\textbf{x}\|^2\cdot \textbf{x}$ is of class $C^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be given by the equation $f(\textbf{x})=\|\textbf{x}\|^2\cdot \textbf{x}$. Show that $f$ is of class $C^\infty$.

I compute and find that $$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = ((x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)x_1, (x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)x_2, \ldots, (x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)x_n).$$

To show that $f$ is of class $C^{\infty}$, it means to show that each component of $f$ is of class $C^{\infty}$. That is, each function $(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)x_i$ is of class $C^{\infty}$. It means for any variables $x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\ldots,x_{i_r}$, we can take partial derivative with respect to those variables, one at a time, and the derivative will exist and is continuous.

In a way, this looks "obvious", because the function $(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)x_i$ consists of just addition and multiplication of the variables, so we can take derivatives using the rules for polynomials. But I don't know how to turn this into a "rigorous" explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polynomials are $C^{\infty}$, since the set of (multivariate) polynomials is closed under partial differentiation in any variable and every polynomial is continuous.

Since the components of $f$ are polynomials, the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

Projections are $C^\infty$, sums and products of $C^\infty$ functions are $C^\infty$.

Comment: I've never seen that fact before. Is it easy to prove? (And does it hold for $C^r$, $r\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ as well?)

Comment: Yes. (And yes). In fact the proof for $C^\infty$ is that it holds for each $r$.