# Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by the equation $f(x) = ||x||^2·x$. Show that $f$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ and that $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by the equation $f(x) = ||x||^2·x$. Show that $f$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ and that $f$ carries the unit ball $B(0, 1)$ onto itself in a one-to-one fashion. Show, however, that the inverse function is not differentiable at $0$.**

I know there are answers to many of the questions of the exercise here:[Function $f(\textbf{x})=\|\textbf{x}\|^2\cdot \textbf{x}$ is of class $C^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479555/function-f-textbfx-textbfx-2-cdot-textbfx-is-of-class-c-infty) , [How to differentiate the function $f(\mathbf x) = \|\mathbf x\|^2 \mathbf x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084095/how-to-differentiate-the-function-f-mathbf-x-mathbf-x-2-mathbf-x) , [To show, that the inverse function is not differentiable at $\mathbf 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389026/to-show-that-the-inverse-function-is-not-differentiable-at-mathbf-0?rq=1)

But I have doubts in showing that  $f$ carries the unit ball $B(0, 1)$ onto itself in a one-to-one fashion, how could I do this? I know I do $||x||<1$ then $||f(x)||<||x||^3<1$, but I do not know how to prove that $f$ is one-to-one in $B(0,1)$. Could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: If $x\neq y$ and $\left\|x\right\|=\left\|y\right\|=r\neq 0$ and $<1$ then $f(x)=\left\|x\right\|^2x=r^2x\neq r^2y=\left\|y\right\|^2y=f(y)$. Also $\left\|\left\|x\right\|^2x\right\|=\left\|x\right\|^2\left\|x\right\|=r^3<1$ and likewise for $y$.

Comment: So by sunwarms argument $f$ maps each sphere $S_r(0)$ bijectively onto $S_{r^3}(0)$ for all $r\in [0,1)$ and since $S_{r_1^3}\cap S_{r_2^3}=\emptyset$ for $0\leq r_1<r_2<1$ $f$ is bijective on the unit ball

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $f$ maps $B(0,1)$ into $B(0,1)$: $\|f(x)\| = \| \|x\|^2 x \| ≤ 1$.
- $f$ is onto: If $y \in B(0,1)$, then note $$f( c y) = c^3 \|y\|^2 y$$ so if $c^3 = \frac1{\|y\|^2}$, $\|cy\| = \|y\|^{-2/3} \|y\| = \|y\|^{1/3} ≤ 1$ so $cy\in B(0,1)$, and $f(cy) = y$.
- $f$ is one-to-one: suppose $\|x\|^2x = \|y\|^2y$. Then $x,y$ are collinear; if $x=0$ there is nothing to show; if $x≠0$, then $y≠0$, and we can write $y=\lambda x$, giving
  $$ x = \lambda^3 x $$
  which implies $\lambda =1$ and hence $x=y$.

Comment: Comment instead of edit to avoid bump - in the onto part, 0 needs to be treated separately to avoid division by zero

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Observe that if $x$ and $y$ are not multiples of each other, then $f(x)\not=f(y)$ since $f(x)$ is a scaled copy of $x$ and $f(y)$ is a scaled copy of $y$.
2. Consider $f(tx)=t^3\|x\|^2x$ for $t>0$.  Since the cube function is injective, so is $f$.  Moreover, since the cube function is surjective, every possible positive scaled copy of $x$ occurs as such an image.
3. Observe that $\|f(x)\|=\|x\|^3$.  Therefore, $\|f(x)\|\leq 1$ iff $\|x\|\leq 1$.